# Xamarin (Android) Resource.Designer.cs generated file has errors

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I started a project and when I try to build I get 120 errors in the Resource.Designer.cs file.

> Error CS0117  'Resource.Color' does not contain a definition for
>   'design_textinput_error_color'

There are 120 similar errors to this one, *'x does not contain a definition for y'*. I tried commenting them out but when I rebuild the file just gets regenerated and the errors return.

Why does it not contain these definitions and how can I get it to create them?

Comment: did you add something to the designer then remove it manually..? do a global search for `design_textinput_error_color` there is probably still a reference to it in the project if worse comes to worse remove the Resource and re-add it..

Comment: I didnt add and remove anything that I'm aware of. Just did a search, thats the one and only reference...

Comment: What is your Android target version set to?

Comment: Compiles using latest platform (android 6.0), min: api 15, target, api 23

Comment: Possibly related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36347287/creating-a-hello-world-in-visual-studio-with-xamarin-forms-fails

In short, ensure these library references are inside your `.csproj`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating Xamarin.Forms in the NuGet manager to the latest version resolved the errors.

Answer (score -1):

You could try:

1. Open up your Android SDK manager and Install the Android 6.0 (API 23).
2. Update Target SDK to API level 23

Try cleaning your build and deleting the obj and bin folders.

Have you seen this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36823998/1107580)?